# Register CDI interceptor without using beans.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I am searching for a way to load a given interceptor programmatically.

I've seen a way to dynamically set an interceptor binding for a given bean, but the interceptor for that binding must be defined in the beans.xml. I know I can use the `@Interceptors` annotation but that way I am tied to a specific implementation.

**Is there a way to load an interceptor (probably through a CDI extension)?**
Or a way to make interceptors enabled by default without the need to declare the `<interceptors></interceptors>`?

I am using Weld-1.1.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to enable an interceptor globally in CDI 1.0 (Weld 1.x), as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming here via a search, like I did, and not being limited to CDI 1.0:
You can add an @Priority() annotation to your interceptor so you don't have to to add it to the beans.xml

```
@MyAnnotation @Interceptor @Priority(Interceptor.Priority.LIBRARY_BEFORE)
public class MyAnnotationInterceptor{...}
```

Comment: Explained here (at the very bottom): https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv006.htm - valid for Java EE 8 as well.